# How do I add a new shell command to eshell?

Tags: emacs, elisp, eshell

Please help me debug the following definition of a simple eshell function.  Yes, I am aware that I can define `l` as an alias, but I need to learn how to write eshell functions.

```
(defun eshell/l (&rest args)
  "a shortcut for ls that automatically adds some flags to the ls"
  (apply #'eshell/ls "-h" "-F" "-t" args))
```

That almost does the right thing. The bug is that the output of the ls command is inserted *after* the new prompt.

Comment: Notes of potential interest: (1) It works without the "-F" argument. (2) It works if you run `eshell/l` explicitly, rather than `l`. (3) If you edit the function definition to match `eshell/ls` exactly, aside from the extra arguments, it still fails. (4) If you add the extra arguments to the `eshell/ls` definition, `ls` still works normally.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done simpler:

```
(defun eshell/l (&rest args)
  "a shortcut for ls that automatically adds some flags to the ls"
  (eshell/ls "-h" "-F" "-t" args))
```

I'm not sure about "-F" (seems does not work on Emacs 24.3 on Windows 7)

Answer (score 0):

Eshell implements alias for this kind of command: http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2010/12/13/complete-guide-mastering-eshell/